# Copying specific named sheets to workbook from all files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am trying to copy specific named worksheets from different workbooks to a main workbook.

I am not sure of my understanding of "IF" statements. If I run my code step by step with a breakpoint on the `endif`, I am getting the result I want, i.e. each worksheet named in each IF statement from each file in my folder, but if I run it normally, my code will only pass through the first IF statement and then switch file. I'll get the first worksheet of each file in my folder.

Can somebody advise me on a solution for this?

By the way, I know that I can do the IF statements in one FOR loop, I just tried to follow it step by step before working on a loop. I also tried to put a wait time in case the error was in the time to open a file or something, but it doesn't look like it is.

```
Sub Import_Files()

Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
   .AllowMultiSelect = False
   .Show
   MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
   Err.Clear
End With

'stops screen updating, calculations, events, and status bar updates to help code run faster
'It'll be opening and closing many files so this will prevent the screen from displaying that

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'This section will loop through and open each file in the folder selected
'and then close that file before opening the next file

Set sThisBk = ActiveWorkbook
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\", vbNormal)

Do While MyFile <> ""
    DoEvents
    'On Error GoTo 0
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE E 000002") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE E 000002")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE E 000003") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE E 000003")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE E 000004") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE E 000004")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE E 000005") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE E 000005")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE E 000006") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE E 000006")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE E 000007") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE E 000007")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE E 000008") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE E 000008")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE E 000009") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE E 000009")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE E 000010") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE E 000010")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE E 000011") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE E 000011")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE E 000012") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE E 000012")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE F30 000002") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE F30 000002")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE F30 000003") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE F30 000003")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE F30 000004") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE F30 000004")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE F30 000005") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE F30 000005")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE F30 000006") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE F30 000006")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE F30 000007") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE F30 000007")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE F30 000008") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE F30 000008")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE F30 000009") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE F30 000009")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE F30 000010") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE F30 000010")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE F30 000011") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE F30 000011")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    If SheetExists("ANALYSE F30 000012") Then
        Set wsSht = Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets("ANALYSE F30 000012")
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisBk.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '0
    Workbooks(MyFile).Close SaveChanges:=False
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

'turns settings back on that was turned off before looping folders

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

End Sub


Private Function SheetExists(sWSName As String) As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Worksheets(sWSName)
If Not ws Is Nothing Then SheetExists = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that your function `SheetExists` doesn't know in which workbook it needs to search. Therefore it needs a parameter for the workbook to look in.

```
Private Function SheetExists(ByVal SheetName As String, Optional InWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Object

    If InWorkbook Is Nothing Then Set InWorkbook = ThisWorkbook 'default to ThisWorkbook 

    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = InWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)
    SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
    On Error Goto 0 'either this or Err.Clear is needed
End Function
```

Then I recommend to define a list of sheet names that should be copied to be able to use a loop:

```
Dim ListOfSheetNames As Variant
ListOfSheetNames = Array("ANALYSE E 000002", "ANALYSE E 000003") 'add more sheet names here
```

Then set your opened workbook to a variable for easier access:

```
Dim OpenedWorkbook As Workbook
Set OpenedWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False)
```

And finally loop through your list of sheet names, test if the sheet names exists in your opened workbook and copy it to `ThisWorkbook` (which is the workbook where this code is running at).

```
Dim SheetName As Variant
For Each SheetName In ListOfSheetNames 'loop through all sheet names in the list
    If SheetExists(SheetName, OpenedWorkbook) Then 'test if sheet name exists in the opened workbook
        OpenedWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ENDOFFILE")
    End If
Next SheetName
```

In the end you can close your opened workbook with

```
OpenedWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```